# The most efficient way to map array to 1 and 0 in Python

Tags: python, arrays

So the task is, to walk `selected_movie_genres` one by one and to put either 1 or 0 to the `result` array by `all_genres` order.

So in the example below, we must check if `Action` is in the list of selected movie genres, then we put 1, else 0. Then we go to the `Adventure`. If the selected movie has it we append 1, not 0.

Only if the selected movie has some genre that is not listed in `all_genres` we put 1 to `Other_genre`'s position as well.

```
          all_genres = ["Action", "Adventure", "Fantasy",
                          "Science Fiction", "Crime", "Drama",
                          "Thriller", "Animation", "Family", "Western",
                          "Comedy", "Romance", "Horror", "Mystery", "History", "War", "Music",
                          "Documentary", "Foreign", "TV Movie", "Other_genre"]
          selected_movie_genres =  [
          {
             "id": 12,
              "name": "Action"
          },
          {
             "id": 18,
             "name": "Drama"
          },
          {
            "id": 878,
            "name": "Autobiography"
          }
         ]
```

So the expected output must be

```
result = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
# Drama, Action and Other_genre categories are on
```

What is the optimal way to achieve this result without repeating ourselves?

Comment: How to use `in`?

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm new to python, having difficult on expressing myself. please help with coding part

Comment: Your expected output is floating point numbers. I suggest that boolean (`True` or `False`) values would be more appropriate.

Comment: Why did my answer get a downvote?  it solves your problem and you can adjust it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very efficient or pythonic but it gets the job done. I'm fairly new at Python but thought I'd give it a go.

```
new = []
ans = []
    
for item in selected_movie_genres:
    new.append(item['name'])

for i in range(len(all_genres)):
    if all_genres[i] in new:
        ans.append(1)
    else:
        ans.append(0)

for item in new:
    if item not in all_genres:
        ans[-1] = ans[-1] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`True` and `False` map to `1` and `0`, so you need to generate a list of `True` and `False` values from `all_genres` depending on if the genre is in `selected_movie_genres` and then map them to their integer values.

First create a collection of just the selected genre names. I used a set here because it should have a faster lookup time when we determine if a genre is in it

```
selected_genres = set(genre['name'] for genre in selected_movie_genres)
```

Then loop over all the genres and returning `True` if it's in the selected genres and `False` if not ( we use `int()` to convert `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`)

```
result = [int(genre_name in selected_genres) for genre_name in all_genres]
```

Comment: what about other genre?

Comment: Does other genre have to be a member of the list? It can be calculated as the length of the input minus the sum of the result

Comment: I'd be more than tempted to make the case for outputting a list of booleans, rather than answer the question exactly as stated. The example output near the end of the question shows floats, although ints are referred to earlier in the description, so the requirement isn't clearly stated anyway. It would be worth asking *why* numeric output is required.

Comment: @alaniwi Agreed. I would also ask why a list of booleans/numbers is required, generating and passing around lists and dictionaries without good reason is a bit of a code smell

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a dictionary from `all_genres` with zero as default value
ag_dic = dict.fromkeys(all_genres, 0.)

#  Check if genre in dictionary;
#   if so, increment by one
#   if not, increment "Other_genre" by one
for genre in selected_movie_genres:
    selected = genre["name"]
    if selected in ag_dic:
        ag_dic[selected] += 1.
    else:
        # We can use the last item in the list to keep it pretty generic
        # assuming that the last item will always be an 'other' category.
        ag_dic[all_genres[-1]] += 1.
```

`ag_dic`:

```
{'Action': 1.0,
 'Adventure': 0.0,
 'Fantasy': 0.0,
 'Science Fiction': 0.0,
 'Crime': 0.0,
 'Drama': 1.0,
 'Thriller': 0.0,
 'Animation': 0.0,
 'Family': 0.0,
 'Western': 0.0,
 'Comedy': 0.0,
 'Romance': 0.0,
 'Horror': 0.0,
 'Mystery': 0.0,
 'History': 0.0,
 'War': 0.0,
 'Music': 0.0,
 'Documentary': 0.0,
 'Foreign': 0.0,
 'TV Movie': 0.0,
 'Other_genre': 1.0}
```

List values of resulting dictionary:

```
result = list(ag_dic.values())
```

`result`

```
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Saw your comment about the downvote. It wasn't me, but it would be worth you making it explicit in your answer that you need a sufficiently recent version of python to rely on the ordering, as you are going via a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks.  That last part (`ag_dic[all_genres[-1]] += 1.`) was originally `ag_dic["Other_genre"] += 1.`  So, that's the only thing relying upon ordering.  Otherwise, I didn't get whether the count would increment or not, or if 1.0/0.0 is all that was needed.  If incremental, this is a good solution.  If for identification, then you could go with a list comprehension.

Answer (score -1):

First would be getting all the selected genres:

```
selected_genres = {movie['name'] for movie in selected_movie_genres}
```

Then go through all the genres and determine if they are in the selection:

```
result = [float(genre in selected_genres) for genre in all_genres]
```

Then for the `'Other_genre'` just figure out if there are any outliers:

```
result[-1] = float(any(genre in all_genres for genre in selected_genres))
```

Comment: `result[-1] = float(any(genre in all_genres for genre in selected_genres))` doesn't work as expected

Comment: How does this not work as expected? It produces a `1.0` if there are any genres not found in `all_genres`